# How to get datas from Linkedin with onLinkedInLoad?

Tags: jquery, oauth, linkedin-api

I have to add a LinkedIn button on a form to prefill inputs with firstname / lastname / email. Everything was OK but one day, my code didn't work anymore...

I created my APPLY on Linkedin to have my api_key. Then, I used a jquery code find on the web to display a button allowing the customer to pre-fill the form below (candidacy for a job) connecting with his Linkedin Profile.

Everything was OK until yesterday : button didn't display anymore.

```
''' html
<script type="in/Login"></script>


''' javascript
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   77vaebcri3ud5i
    lang:      fr_FR
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    function getProfileData(){
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["firstName","lastName", "email-address"]).result(function(data) {

            var profileData = data.values[0];

            $('#form_nom').val(profileData.lastName);
            $('#form_prenom').val(profileData.firstName);
            $('#form_email').val(profileData.emailAddress);

            $('#titreconnexionlinkedin').html('<h3>Vous êtes connecté via Linkedin en tant que<br /><strong>'+profileData.firstName+' '+profileData.lastName+'</strong></h3>');

        });  
    }
</script>
```

I have this javascript error :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Could not instantiate tag for 'login': Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at new  (Login.js?version=0.1.149:7)
    at in.js:18

and the login.js :
https://platform.linkedin.com/xdoor/extensions/Login.js?version=0.1.149